# Datatable click event on header not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have put one checkbox in header for the select other check boxes but click event not working on header.

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#example').on('click','.checkAll', function () {
    alert("hi");
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.otherChechBox').prop('checked', true);
        selected = [];
        $(".otherChechBox:checked").each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        });
    } else {
        $('.otherChechBox').prop('checked', false);
        selected = [];
    }
});
});
```

HTML Code

```
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed-column order-column dataex-column-width">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center col-md-1"><input class="checkAll" name="agree" id="checkAll" type="checkbox" ></th>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Permission Parent</th>
                            <th>Permission Name</th>
                            <th>Slug</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($permissions as $permission)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><input class="otherChechBox" name="agree[]" id="{{$permission->id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}"></td>
                            <td>{{$permission->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$permission->permission_parent}}</td>
                            <td>{{$permission->permission_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$permission->slug}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{url('/Admin/permission/edit',$permission->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:20px;"></i></a>
                                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size:20px;color:red;"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

i have also tried this

```
$('#example').on('click','.checkAll', function () {..});
```

click event working perfectly in `<td>` but not working in `<th>`

Comment: Can you post a sample snippet?

Comment: means should i paste whole file of html & js?

Comment: Nope.. Just kind of sample demo as in what is not working would be fine.

Comment: i have updated the code,please check it. click event is not working on header of datatable and i already tried so many solution but nothing works

Comment: did you included jQuery library? also wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

Comment: yes, i did that but still i think not working due to datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have figured out,its work with below snippet.

```
$('#example thead th').on('click','.checkAll', function () {..});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the js code in document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#example').on('click','.checkAll', function () {
    alert("hi");
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('.otherChechBox').prop('checked', true);
        selected = [];
        $(".otherChechBox:checked").each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        });
    } else {
        $('.otherChechBox').prop('checked', false);
        selected = [];
    }
});
});
```

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#example').on('click','.checkAll', function () {
        alert("hi");
    });
    });
```

Try above code first to check if the event is being triggered or not. If you get the alert there is another issue in your js.

### Update 2

Try using Onclick on input.

```
<input class="checkAll" name="agree" id="checkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxfunction()" >

<script>
function checkboxfunction(){
alert("clicked");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you check your console? What error are you getting?

Comment: no event is not triggered and that what the issue is and i think event not triggered due to datatable.

Comment: Try with onclick on input as I have shown in my answer. Check if it works?

Comment: my js code is on another file and i have called it externally so it give me error checkboxFunction is not defined

Comment: Show the code where you have included your scripts? Need to check order of included scripts.

Comment: check out here [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YBL-oQYnhTux7ElPBHtGY61WL6vBFl7A]

Comment: 404 not found. @SagarBhagdev

Comment: sorry,check now [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YBL-oQYnhTux7ElPBHtGY61WL6vBFl7A/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Move your custom.js script at the end of the page. Just after where you have written the code for $("#example").datatable.

Comment: Try to move your click event code in same file. Lets see if it works?

Comment: Thanks for your help dude, i have solved it and i have already posted it,check it below and give +1 to question and answer if you think its an good question and proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check all other checkboxes in the table, when clicking on the `.checkAll` checkbox ?

See snippet below, let me know if this is what you wanted.

```js
$('#example').on('click', '.checkAll', function() {
  let otherCheck = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this)
  otherCheck.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed-column order-column dataex-column-width">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center col-md-1">
        <input class="checkAll" name="agree" id="checkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Permission Parent</th>
      <th>Permission Name</th>
      <th>Slug</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <input class="" name="" id="" type="checkbox">
  <input class="" name="" id="" type="checkbox">
  <input class="" name="" id="" type="checkbox">



</table>
```

Comment: yeah i want the same but click event not working with this `$('#example').on('click', '.checkAll', function() { ..});`

Comment: @SagarBhagdev what do you mean not working with this ? i used the same in my answer ... and it works

Comment: yeah you are right but its not working with datatable `var table = $('#example').DataTable( {..});`

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue.

Datatable  was firing

```
$('#example').on('change','input[type="checkbox"]'....
```

for me when checkbox was in thead  UNTIL  I scrolled the table and the heading  became fixed at the top (using the extra fixedHeader.min.js  setting).  The `on('change')` then no longer fired if I ticked/unticked the checkbox in the heading.

Adding in an extra

```
$('#example thead th').on('click', '#myclickfield', function () {
```

fired every time  (i.e. whether heading was visible as part of table, or only visible as part of the  fixedheader redisplay of heading row).